# How to make a div and its children to ignore its parent styles?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Lets say I have the following markup:-

```
<div class="house">
  <p>...</p>
  <div class="room">
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="house">
  <p>...</p>
  <div class="room porch">
     <p>...</p>
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
.house .room { /* Some styling done here */ }

.porch { /* Some different styling done here */ }
```

Now, I'd like my div with the classes `room` and `porch` to consider only the class `porch` and ignore the styles of `house` and `room`. Is this possible? This is just a simple example, I have a case where in place of the class `porch`, there are many more classes, so overriding just one class with `!important` won't work, as there could be a lot of classes with various styles.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use `:not`

```
.house .room:not(.porch) { 
      /* .room elements only when they have not .porch class */ 
}

.porch { 
      /* all .porch elements */
}
```

Browser support : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of which selector is in effect for the chosen styling rule.

1. Selectors which come later in the styling order overrule the ones that come before
2. Selectors with a higher specificity overrule the ones with lower specificity even if the latter come after the former

So make this selector.
`. house .room.porch`